# Cannot add cascade on update on two column of table referencing to same table same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, cascade

I'm using SQL Server.

I have one table named `PROGRAM_MASTER` which has two columns `created_by` and `updated_by` which are referencing to `USERS` table on column `id`.

Now I want to define cascade on update option to both these columns using below SQL command.

```
alter table program_master add constraint program_master_created_by_foreign foreign key (created_by) references users (id) on update cascade

alter table program_master add constraint program_master_upated_by_foreign foreign key (updated_by) references users (id) on update cascade
```

But foreign key constraint gets added to `created_by`, but while creating one for `updated_by` I get following error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
> 'program_master_updated_by_foreign' on table 'program_master' may
> cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How should I resolve this error?

Comment: How you should resolve this is right there in the error message isn't it? - `Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.` With that being said, why do you even need this? i.e. In what scenario would you update a users id? Your best bet is to address why you would want to update a primary key rather than worrying about how to manage the referential integrity when it happens.

Comment: The error of cycles in cascading FK constraints has been discussed many times; just search the internet. The short answer is - you cannot use the cascade option in situations like this and will need to manage this update logic in code.